# Why are changes to master not appearing in my GitHub merge heads?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull-request

I'm troubleshooting an issue with TeamCity building GitHub pull requests, as described in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity), and I'm trying to replicate the checkout behaviour locally.

Here's the sequence of steps I'm following:

```
// in /projects/semver_demo/master 
git checkout master
echo "Hello World!" > master.txt
git add .
git commit -m "edited master.txt"
git push
git branch foo
echo "Hello World!" > foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git push
```

Now I go to GitHub, open pull request #123 from branch `foo`. Then in a separate repo that I've checked out in a different folder, I'm checking out what I believe to be the current **merge head** for pull request #123:

```
// in /projects/semver_demo/merged
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/merge:pr123
git checkout pr123
```

OK, so far, so good - I'm on a branch containing my feature. Now, I'm going to go back to my working folder, simulate making some changes to master, which - as I understand it - should appear when I fetch the merge head again.

```
// in /projects/semver_demo/master
git checkout master
echo "Hello again!" >> master.txt
git add master.txt
git commit -m "Added another line to master.txt"
git push
```

Now, switch back to my feature_branch folder and delete and re-fetch the merge head:

```
// in /projects/semver_demo/merged
git checkout master
git branch -D pr123
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/merge:pr123
git checkout pr123
```

When I do this, I expected to see the new "Hello again!" message in `merged/master.txt`, but I'm not - I'm seeing the same version of `master.txt` that existed when the branch was created.

My understanding was that a merge head would give you the equivalent of merging the current master (or upstream branch) into the current HEAD of the feature branch - but that's not what I'm seeing. Have I missed some subtle step to tell Git to "re-merge" the merge head? Or have I completely misunderstood the purpose of merge heads?

**EDIT:** After a little more investigation, pushing changes to `foo` DOES cause the merge head to reflect the latest changes to `master`... but pushing changes to `master` doesn't. I'm wondering now if this behaviour is by design?

Comment: Do you see the SHA for the merge HEAD change after that second fetch?

I actually think that the merge HEAD only changes when you change the tip of the branch, but I'd need to setup a similar repro and confirm this is the case.

Comment: @BrendanForster how would I check this? I've primarily worked with Git via various GUI tools and so don't have a huge amount of experience working with the underlying data structures directly...

Comment: run `git rev-parse HEAD` after you've checked out the `pr123` ref - if the object ID is different between both usages, it means GitHub has tried to create a new merge commit. You can then `git show HEAD` to see which commits it has tried to merge, and you can correlate these to which branches you have locally...

Comment: OK. Pushing changes to master doesn't change the SHA of the pr123 branch - but pushing a change to the branch (foo) creates a new SHA, and also causes it to pick up the latest changes to master. Is it possible that GitHub's merge heads are updated when a change is pushed to the branch, but NOT when a change is pushed to master?

Comment: **Is it possible that GitHub's merge heads are updated when a change is pushed to the branch, but NOT when a change is pushed to master?** I believe this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: So, IIRC Github pull request pages have a slightly odd behaviour, in that they'll do certain rebuilds only when you visit the page (presumably to avoid the high load of rebuilding many things all the time). Have you tried refreshing the PR web page after pushing the changes to master?

Comment: I've opened a GitHub support request to see if I can get some clarification around how merge heads behave. I'll update this page once I've had a response.

Comment: Confirmation from GitHub support saying "we can confirm that we do not update the PR when the base branch changes, only when the head branch is updated."

So looks like we'll need to introduce an explicit merge step into our build and release process rather than relying on merge heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified with GitHub support that merge heads are only updated when changes are pushed to the head branch; they do not update to reflect changes to the base branch - so if you're building prerelease packages based on pull request merge heads, always push a change to the PR branch immediately before building the package. If you're using VCS triggers to start your package builds, this should happen anyway, so I think this is one of those obscure edge cases that won't actually happen very often in real life.

There's more detailed notes on this, and how it affects the GitHubFlow workflow we're using, at http://www.dylanbeattie.net/2017/01/semantic-versioning-with-powershell_26.html